# Redis + “source of truth” DB consistency

Tags: database, database-design, redis

I'm building an analytics tool and am facing some performance issues with time-series based metrics. I've been experimenting with Redis + bitmapist which allows me to eagerly prepare metrics at the time of DB writes and very pleased with the performance.

However, I'm a little confused about how to ensure my DB and Redis remain synchronized. My DB is the "source of truth" storing all event data, but user dashboards will rely on Redis for displaying metrics.

Should I be doing periodic complete re-builds of my Redis metrics to make sure there is no discrepancies between my DB and Redis? (ex: when an event occurs, it is written to the DB, but fails to write to Redis)

If my Redis server goes down, it will take a long time to re-process all events and rebuild metrics. Should my dashboards query the DB as a backup plan, even though the DB query logic for a particular metric is completely different from Redis query logic?

Comment: Complete rebuilds on occasion seem reasonable, but how perfect does a dashboard really need to be?

Comment: This is true, it doesn't need to be perfect. I just want to reduce the chance of inaccuracy as much as possible.

Comment: Redis has data persistency (on by default) so no need to worry about a complete rebuild, only the deltas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are referring to here is the problem of maintaining cache consistency.

First you need to decide how stale is too stale for the dashboard. Once you have that, use that as your limit and set an expiration for data stored in Redis. Note that  how exactly you do that is tightly coupled to how you choose to store the results in Redis.

Next have your dashboard do a "get or store" sequence. This means you first query the Redis setup for the data and, if found, display it. If not found you query your source DB, store the result in Redis, set appropriate expiration, and display it. For reboot or restart cache warming let Redis persists to disk (which it does by default) and you will not lose the entries on restart - except for expired ones of course.

This process will minimize the risk of outdated data while providing a direct update on data as it is requested. The other option is to have whatever is storing the events in your original DB also store in Redis.  That option, however, will mean a complete duplication of data as opposed to only keeping the "hot", or select, items from the dashboard in Redis to improve dashboard performance.

Comment: Having the ability to 'hydrate' cache from your source of truth should be done at a minimum.  I'm also a big proponent of setting the expiry (you have to do it on every update) as un-used data won't be wasting expensive memory.  You could also consider forcibly deleting keys if a past update has failed.  Then on the next request for the data, the correct set will be put into cache.

Answer (score -1):

Writes on Redis should be done using a *reliable service bus* so they can be retried as many times as needed to perform the write:

- [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/).
- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

That way, your system will be more reliable, because a message queue or service bus can provide settings for defining that a message can be dequeued unsucessfully 1, 2 or 1K times. If writing metrics to Redis fails because a Redis is down, no problem: an asynchronous process will try to write to Redis again, and so on.

It might happen that your Redis database could remain unsynchronized for some seconds, minutes or even an hour, but you know that your system will try to recover its normal state as soon as a temporal issue is solved.

In the other hand, since Redis 3.0, you've [*Redis Cluster*](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), a built-in sharding approach to Redis. That is, you can partition your data in two or more Redis servers. This is important to avoid that a single server down could affect the entire service to your customers.

In addition, Redis has data [persistency to disk](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

I believe I've already gave enough tips and tools to realize that you should be able to reliably synchronize your definitive store with your Redis-based *fast* store.

Comment: Neither a service bus nor cluster has anything to do with this question.

Comment: @TheRealBill This is your point, not mine. It has a lot of to do with this question, because the OP wants to be sure that both databases are synchronized, and a service bus can provide a GOOD way of retrying writes on Redis to avoid data loss.

Comment: @TheRealBill I've enhanced my answer to reflect what I mean with using Cluster and a service bus. I wouldn't downvote an answer just because I don't understand the background behind it. I would just ask for more info.....

Comment: It doesn't address the issue asked, but one you decided to answer. Cluster has nothing to do with the question because it has nothing to do with cache consistency, and doesn't provide HA relevant to the question. A service bus does nothing to specifically provide consistency either. I understood what you said, but it doesn't address the question. The sync doesn't happen because of a service bus, it happens because you write code to do the work. Advocating only writing to Redis via a service bus isn't solving the problem or answering the question, but simply pushing other tech stacks.

Comment: The OP does ask for advice on how to mitigate cache write errors.  A durable queuing mechanism is a solution to this problem.  But in the case of an analytic platform, a retry queue can cause late updates which could lead to corrupt data if out of sequence updates are a problem.  This is something to consider.

Comment: @DrewBeaupre Well, it might depend on the retry interval. You're right that it can lead to exposing outdated/corrupted data, but at least, the system is able to continue its work automatically because the data corruption case is covered. So... I expect to also have a success/fail queue and the UI (and/or other consumers) should be notified about the success or fail. This is interesting because the error queue can be consumed by some API proxy to let the UI get the data from the definitive storage instead of Redis without knowing it

Comment: @TheRealBill Sorry, but you're mistaken. My answer provides a possible solution. Obviously, a Q&A isn't an encyclopedia and I just give some hints that can be interesting for the OP to build a powerful software architecture that can solve the issue by design